# What is an ideal binding agent for wood ash?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have some wood ash left over after extracting potash. I want to make biocomposites as per the below link. https://materiom.org/recipe/59

The recipe uses agar agar which is a food grade material and quite expensive. Since this will not be used as food, I do not need to use food grade material. Hence, looking for a substitute.

As per my understanding agar agar and cornstarch give the binding effect differently. One gives while cooling, other while heating. Can I use corn starch instead of agar agar? Any other binding agent is also fine. Any other recipes for wood ash biocomposites are also fine.

Is the calcium propionate really necessary?

On a related note: a lot of wood ash is calcium carbonate. Some of it is calcium oxide. Will the biocomposite work if it is calcium oxide?

Appreciate the assistance

Comment: 1. Calcium (and Na and K) propionate is a common, approved food preservative, added to comestibles such as bread and cakes. It is safe to assume the only purpose is to preserve the finished item. 2. If the ash is fresh, the Ca will be mostly as oxide, but slightly dampened and exposed to air, in a few days it should convert to the carbonate.